# Loading of data in the data table is taking 45 to 60 seconds long with server side processing

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables, server-side-rendering

I've used server side processing to render 60K records into the data tables. My SQL query is taking 10 seconds to get all the records(60K records). But the rendering time is taking long like, 45 to 60 seconds. I've tested it in my local system in which it took 2 to 3 seconds to render. Whereas on server, its taking the above mentioned time. What would be the cause of this problem and how to solve this?

Following is the query I've used.

```
SELECT a.asset_id, a.asset_name, a.asset_code,ifnull(tickets,0)as tickets, 
    a.asset_serialNo,a.asset_price,a.asset_description,a.createdAt,a.updatedAt,a.status,
    aty.assetType_name,p.project_Name,l.location_name, dw3.dropdown_name  FROM assets a      
    LEFT join assettypes aty on a.asset_type = aty.assetType_id  
    Left join projects p on a.project_id =p.project_id
    Left JOIN project_locations l on a.location_id=l.id
    Left JOIN admin_dropdowns dw3 ON a.assetStatus=dw3.id 
    left join asset_ticket_count_view atl on a.asset_id=atl.asset_id
    where a.asset_name <> 'No Asset Serial No' AND a.location_id=$location order by 
    a.asset_id desc
```

This is the function am using for data table.

```
var dataTable=$('#contactDetail').dataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "pagingType": "numbers",
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    order: [[4,"desc"]],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
           'copyHtml5',
            {
               extend: 'excelHtml5',
               title: 'Assets List',
               footer: true,
               exportOptions: {
                  columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                  modifier: {
                     page: 'all',
                     search: 'none'   
                  },
               }
            },{
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                title: 'Assets List',
                footer: true,
                exportOptions: {
                   columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   modifier: {
                      page: 'all',
                      search: 'none'   
                   },
                }
            },
    ],
    "ajax": {
        url:query_url,
    },
    'columnDefs': [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": 7 },
        {
           'targets': [0],
           'render': function(data, type, full, meta){
               if(type === 'display'){
                  data = strtrunc(data, 15);
               }
               return data;
            }
         },{
              'targets': [2],
              'render': function(data, type, full, meta){
                  if(type === 'display'){
                     data = strtrunc(data, 15);
                  }
                  return data;
               }
         },{
              'targets': [6],
              'render': function(data, type, full, meta){
                   let p3;
                   url='tickets.php?asset_count='+full[full.length - 1];
                   p3='<a href="'+url+'">'+full[full.length - 2]+'</a>'
                   return p3;
                }
         },{
               'targets': [7],
               'render': function(data, type, full, meta){
                   let p1,p2;
                   <?php 
                        if (in_array($perm2, $_SESSION['Edit'])){ ?>
                           url='NewAsset.php?id='+data;
                           p1='<a href="'+url+'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary fa fa-edit"></a>'
                   <?php } else { ?>
                          p1= '';
                   <?php }?>
                   <?php 
                       if (in_array($perm2, $_SESSION['Delete'])){ ?>
                           url='assets.php?delete='+data;
                           p2= '<a href="'+url+'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete?\')" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger fa fa-trash""></a>'
                   <?php } else { ?>
                         p2= '';
                   <?php }?>
                   return p1+' '+p2;
                }, 
        }]
} );
```

Comment: Can you post the code which is causing the problem.  If it's a large amount of code then try and reduce it to the particular segment which causes the biggest problem.

Comment: Hi @NigelRen , I've edited my question with the code am using.

Comment: It really is a lot of records for a database query but also to render - even if it's performing well locally. Do you have to display all of them on the page right away? My suggestion would be to load and render only records that can be fit within the browser window and then make another call and parse when the next section scrolls into view. This way you should increase the performance significantly. Then, even if you're using filter / search, you can fetch records matching the filter and also only return number of records that fits within the window.

Comment: Hi @SebastianSulinski , no, am loading 10 records at a time. The data table and the server side processing that I've used will make an API call for every page

Comment: Hi @Aravind - are you actually fetching only 10 records at a time using `limit` with `offset` or you are only rendering 10 at a time in the browser? You say `My SQL query is taking 10 seconds to get all the records(60K records)` so I understood that you are actually fetching all 60K of records? Also - any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Show your query. This code does not help finding the bottleneck. Are there indexes?

Comment: No errors available on console. I just mentioned the number of records and I've executed the query and mentioned the time taken. And I dont know how exactly the data is rendering.

Comment: Hi @MarkusZeller , please see the code. I've edited with the query.

Comment: Do you have indexes? There should be on all fields are used in where clause and all fields are used "on" join.

Comment: No @MarkusZeller . Index is available for only asset_id

Comment: Add those for joins and where clause, and you will see some magic.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MarkusZeller. If that's the issue, then why am I not facing the problem on local system and facing the issue on server?

Comment: Maybe your PC has enough RAM that mySQL can cache the results.

Comment: Okay, my RAM is having 4GB of size

Comment: Can be so many factors: RAM, Disk I/O, CPU speed, other services running. But the main key for DB is using indexes very smart.

Comment: So you think adding indexes might solve the issue?

Comment: Sure. Didn't it?

Comment: I'll check it out and let you know. Thanks